# Create Stack Overflow questions for teams from Slack

Tags: feature-request, stack-overflow-for-teams

Are there any plans for the Stack Overflow for teams to allow the Slack integration to ask questions directly from Slack and post them on Stack Overflow for teams?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

While I don't have a firm roadmap to share on exactly when different features will ship for Stack Overflow for Teams, I can say that integrations into other systems are a substantial focus and priority for us.

You can expect to see both a more robust Slack integration (we've specifically talked about asking questions from Slack, as well as searching from there) as well as integrations to additional systems, including both other chat systems and other types of systems.  Stay tuned for more details - we'll be announcing new features as they come [on the blog](https://stackoverflow.blog/for-work/).

Answer (score 1):

Slack integration [has been recently announced](https://stackoverflow.blog/2018/11/14/announcing-our-new-partnership-with-slack/). For a list of highlights, check [this article](https://stackoverflow.com/teams/integrations/slack):

- Instant Notifications
- Start Questions from Slack
- Search for Answers in Slack